# High Powered C++ Macros - Loop Expansion for Generating Overloads

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

**Summary:**

In short, a couple macros can be used to duplicate a function definition N times. Specified variables or arguments could be expanded N times during the Nth definition.

To be very specific [this file](https://bitbucket.org/rgaul/sel/src/32fd2e5fb1085cd1ad789ac3a5d68111b03dc450/src/SEL/Introspection/SELFunctionPtr.h?at=default) can be shortened dramatically *somehow* with some clever macros.

I've already seen the solution using the `#include` directive, and I'm pretty sure the `#include` directive isn't needed.

**Details:**

I've seen a codebase I no longer have access to create function overloads with some macros. I want to recreate this functionality but can only remember bits and pieces of implementation. The idea is some function overloads like so:

```
void func( int a0 )
{
}

void func( int a0, int a1 )
{
}

void func( int a0, int a1, int a2 )
{
}
```

could be created with some macro like this:

```
void func( LOOP_ME( int a ) )
{
}
```

Where LOOP_ME is a macro. The idea was to wrap any arguments, or variables, within the function you want duplicated in a LOOP_ME macro.

I recall the codebase had something like this within it:

```
#define LOOP_ME1( x ) x##0
#define LOOP_ME2( x ) x##0, x##1
#define LOOP_ME3( x ) x##0, x##1, x##2
```

The codebase was *definitely* using the macro overloading trick as described here: http://efesx.com/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/ . However, I don't remember specifically what this trick was used for in the implementation.

An additional feature was that a function need only be written once. So somehow the entire definition of `func` in my example would have been duplicated N times, and in my example N is hard-coded to 3. I don't remember the mechanism for duplicating the function in question, but I am guessing the codebase used something like this:

```
INPUT_TEXT(
    void func( LOOP_ME( int a ) ) \
    { \
    } \
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how this might be accomplished with macros alone?

Comment: [This guy](http://ooc-coding.sourceforge.net/) created an entire object oriented system using macros.  Maybe you could study it and see how he did it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm taking a look, but maybe I wasn't clear. This isn't about recreating C++ features in C, it's just about duplicating text and expanding argument/variable names.

Comment: The boost.preprocessor preprocessor library provides tools to do that. You could either use them directly or look up how they've implemented it.

Comment: What is the use case of this macro? Is it that bad to pass 3 variables? If there are many, send an array.

Comment: @dyp Boost was not used.

Comment: @NeilKirk The use is to write `func` only once. `func` is expanded N times, and specific variables can be duplicated N times during the Nth expansion.

Comment: What is the body of the function?

Comment: `#define LOOP_ME(X, N) LOOP_ME ## N (X)`, then you can write `void func( LOOP_ME(int a, 5) )`.

Comment: @dyp That's progress, but the `func` function needs to be duplicated N times too without the user copy/pasting it N times. Only 1 definition of `func` should be written by the user.

Comment: Which compiler are you using/supporting?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the problem. I think you can only pass arguments to "inner" macros by either `#include`ing or passing explicitly, e.g. `#define INPUT_TEXT(N) void func( LOOP_ME(int a, N) ) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @HWalters I would like to support all major ones. I'm specifically using VS 2012.

Comment: @dyp I think that's really close. Maybe another macro could use INPUT_TEXT( N ) macro N times. The goal is for the user not to copy/paste anything N times.

Comment: Ack... MSVS's preprocessor is a bit "broken"; it'll be hard to standardize a CPPMP to handle both normal and VS preprocessing semantics unfortunately.  (Though this could still be done using "uglier" techniques...)

Comment: @HWalters I'm familiar :( If a solution would work with g++ without using non-standard extensions, I'm sure I could find a workaround for myself for VS. I would accept an answer in this form.

Comment: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc3f77d661d84a9) -- but again, this uses explicit argument passing -- seems to work in VS2013 as well

Comment: @dyp I think that would work! I did say that N was hardcoded, so that's perfectly fine that you explicitly pass it around. Is there a way to do this without defining a macro for the function definition, such that the text can be passed into a macro (like the INPUT_TEXT example)?

Comment: It may sound like a stupid question, but: _why just not define the function with the most parameters and set them to a default value which is a neutral element?_

Comment: @PawełStawarz I think that would work in some but not all cases. In the example file I linked to in the OP neutral elements wouldn't work since templates are used to describe function pointers and their arguments.

Comment: Without `#include`? I do not know how.. You have to replace the `LOOP_ME` macro with different things depending on iteration of the outer repetition (of the function). This part (`LOOP_ME(int a)`) can only be a macro, but there is not state that could be changed inside the macro invocation of `INPUT_TEXT` (as opposed to inside a file).

Comment: @dyp Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify N during the Nth definition unless the function is defined in a macro, or `#include` from another file. If that's the case I'd be willing to accept an answer like your live example. The user need only define one function, and there's no copy/pasting N times.

Comment: @RandyGaul But aren't you asking about how to make sure you can generate the _functions_, and not merely the prototypes with empty bodies?

Comment: @RandyGaul: variadic templates are a better solution to what your sample code is trying to achieve. I've implemented similar systems for reflection and script binding to what you have entirely with variadics. Another nice benefit of those over macros are that you can actually set breakpoints and debug them (at runtime).

Comment: FYI, waiting on response to my question and/or @SeanMiddleditch before proceeding; specifically, if you don't need to support legacy compilers (pre-C11), you don't need a PP solution and the variadic solution should be given instead.

Comment: @HWalters C11 is fine, but I'm not interested in templated solutions. Not sure what PP solutions means, and I can use dyp's example to define function bodies *and* signatures.

Comment: @RandyGaul (C11 is typo FYI; should be C++11) Sure, but given this already uses templates, using variadics has tons of advantages (generalizing indefinitely; more readable; better compiler support).  "Not sure what PP" PP=preprocessor--what you were asking for. "I can use dyp's example" Indeed you can, but ideally you want your macro to mimic like your code.  The issue is internal heterogeneous repetition (sometimes you want "int a1, int a2"; sometimes "typename Arg1 arg1, typename Arg2 arg2", etc).  You'd need a custom macro for each of these, which cripples readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and help from both dyp and HWalter in the comments I've come up with a good solution that should work on any decent compiler. Here is an example of what we want to generate:

```
void func( int a1 )
{
    int args[] = {
        a1
    };

    args[1 - 1] = 1;
}

void func( int a1, int a2 )
{
    int args[] = {
        a1,
        a2
    };

    args[1 - 1] = 1;
    args[2 - 1] = 2;
}

void func( int a1, int a2, int a3 )
{
    int args[] = {
        a1,
        a2,
        a3
    };

    args[1 - 1] = 1;
    args[2 - 1] = 2;
    args[3 - 1] = 3;
}
```

Here is the code to generate the above functions:

```
#define PARAMS( N ) \
    int a##N

#define COLLECT_PARAMS( N ) \
    a##N

#define ACCESS_PARAMS( N ) \
    args[N - 1] = N;

#define FUNC( N ) \
    void func( LOOP( PARAMS, N ) ) \
    { \
        int args[] = { \
            LOOP( COLLECT_PARAMS, N ) \
        }; \
    \
        PRINT( ACCESS_PARAMS, N ) \
    }

ITERATE( FUNC, 3 )
```

And here are the definitions for `LOOP`, `PRINT` and `ITERATE`. Please note that `LOOP` and `PRINT` only differ in their usage of the `,` operator.

```
#define ITERATE_0( F )
#define ITERATE_1( F ) F( 1 )
#define ITERATE_2( F ) ITERATE_1( F ) F( 2 )
#define ITERATE_3( F ) ITERATE_2( F ) F( 3 )

#define ITERATE( F, N ) ITERATE_##N( F )

#define LOOP_0( F, N )
#define LOOP_1( F, N ) F( 1 )
#define LOOP_2( F, N ) LOOP_1( F, N ), F( 2 )
#define LOOP_3( F, N ) LOOP_2( F, N ), F( 3 )

#define LOOP( F, N ) LOOP_##N( F, N )

#define PRINT_0( F, N )
#define PRINT_1( F, N ) F( 1 )
#define PRINT_2( F, N ) PRINT_1( F, N ) F( 2 )
#define PRINT_3( F, N ) PRINT_2( F, N ) F( 3 )

#define PRINT( F, N ) PRINT_##N( F, N )
```

This works by calling a macro N times. The macro called N times will generate N functions (and could have generated something other than functions). Inside of each invocation interior loops can be run. An interior loop runs recursively N times.

It's important to place all text to be generated within an interior loop inside of a callable macro so that parentheses and commas don't screw up the macro API, since these delimit macros on their own.

N has an upper limit of 3, and works if 0 is passed to it (nothing will be generated). The upper limit can be expanded simply by making more recursive macros of the form `LOOP_N`, `PRINT_N` and `ITERATE_N`.